# jQuery pushing additional calculated data points to HighChart series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to push data points to a data series array for HighCharts. I have started with the standard pie template. I have then added additional $.get statements to calculate the number of lines in the files.
The alert statement on each additional $.get returns the correct number of lines, but the data point is not pushed to the series.
Can anyone help me, I am new to JQuery. Thanks.

```
                $.get('piechart.csv', function(data) {
                    // Split the lines
                    var buttons
                    var lines = data.split('\n');
                    var series = {
                        data: []
                    };
                    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo,line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');
                            series.data.push({
                                name: items[0],
                                y:parseFloat(items[1])
                            });
                    });


                    $.get('button0.txt', function(data) {
                        // Split the lines
                        var lines = data.split('\n');
                        series.data.push({
                            name: 'Power off',
                            y: (lines.length-1)
                        });
                        alert (lines.length-1);
                    });
                    $.get('button1.txt', function(data) {
                        // Split the lines
                        var lines = data.split('\n');
                        series.data.push({
                            name: 'Power on',
                            y: (lines.length-1)
                        });
                        alert (lines.length-1);
                    });

                    options.series.push(series);
                    // Create the chart
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
```

Comment: AJAX calls are async, so lines aren't executed one-by-one. Read about `jQuery.done` or waterfall ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

The data point *is*, I would assume, being pushed to the series, but the problem lies in the fact that this doesn't happen until after you have already created and rendered your chart instance.

Leaving aside the fact that I don't see a declaration of the `options` variable in your code, which would suggest that there might be another bug lurking (but I'm assuming that's just a typo?), the problem lies in the fact that HighCharts doesn't do anything to track the initial series that you pass it, so modifying that series isn't going to affect the chart.

You'll need to update the chart yourself - using, for example, [the addPoint method of the HighCharts series object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint). So, in the success callback for your Ajax calls, you'll need to do something along the lines of:

```
$.get('button0.txt', function(data) {
     // Split the lines
     var lines = data.split('\n'),
         chart = $('#container').highcharts();
     chart.series[0].addPoint({ 
           name: 'Power off', 
           y: lines.length-1 
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick. The 'options' declaration was a little further up the code and seemed to work so I didn't include it.
Thanks very much for the help.